# What folders does Linux have that Mac OS X doesn't?

Tags: linux, macos

I was wondering what kind of folders Linux has by default (e.g. system folders such as `/var`, `/tmp` etc) that Mac OS X doesn't?

I'm pretty sure that some of these folders exist in Mac OS X but are hidden; is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides

```
/proc
```

and

```
/sys
```

You often find these at the root of Linux ( Ubuntu in this case ) and not typically on OS X:

```
/boot
/intrd
/lib
/lost+found
/media
/mnt
/root
/srv
```

Comment: Yea thanks, I was planning to use this with Ubuntu too. Thanks!!

Comment: *lost+found* is more of a filesystem feature than a system-provided folder.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least /proc and /sys are on Linux but not on OS X. Both proc an sys are not on disk filesystems, they are virtual filesystems that give an interface into various aspects of the running kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Linux typically uses `/home` for user home directories, whereas OS X uses `/Users`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the /proc directory (procfs), there actually is a version available for OS X.  It's bundled into the [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) source.  Most of the information you probably want is there, but not always in the way that Linux presents it.